# Optional group and backref counting with sed

Tags: bash, sed, backreference

I'm about exchanging the value of key/value pairs in configurations and wondering how to accomplish this in sed when backrefs can have different indices:

```
$ echo "#foo=bar" | sed "s|^\(#\)\(foo=\)\(.*\)|\2new_bar|g"
foo=new_bar
```

Fine. But, it can be, that the comment sign is not there, so the first group (#) is not there. -Then \2 would be actually \1.

```
$ echo "foo=bar" | sed "s|^\(#\)\(foo=\)\(.*\)|\2new_bar|g"
foo=bar
```

The sed should work in either way substituting `bar` by `new_bar`. How can I determine the correct backref number with sed or is it possible to define an optional field otherwise that with a group?

**EDIT:**

Actually, my description for the second case is wrong because the regex doesn't match, because the `#` is not in the searched string at all. So no backreferences can match. I've just missed the quantifier `\?` for the `#` which yields to an actual group whether or not the sign exists. Thanks to @ruak for pointing this out.

Comment: Note that your description of what's happening is wrong. (Did you notice that it doesn't account for the output you're seeing?)

Comment: @ruak Now I see.... The second try doesn't work with \1 either, because the regex doesn't match at all when the single `#` is missing. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Right. `\2` *never* becomes `\1`. The numbering of capture-groups is a static/lexical property of the regex, and is not affected by the matching process.

Comment: @ruak I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help?

```
sed "s|^\(#\?\)\(foo=\)\(.*\)|\2new_bar|g"
```

with your string:

```
kent$  echo "#foo=bar" | sed "s|^\(#\?\)\(foo=\)\(.*\)|\2new_bar|g" 
foo=new_bar

kent$  echo "foo=bar" | sed "s|^\(#\?\)\(foo=\)\(.*\)|\2new_bar|g" 
foo=new_bar
```

Comment: Phew, how easy, I should have known... `\? As *, but only matches zero or one.` and this results to a group always. Thanks a lot.